# How to find which integer reaches 0 first?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a project and am looking for help.

My setup is this:

```
Integer 1 - (equation) = Integer 1a 
Integer 2 - (equation) = Integer 2a

Integer 1a - (equation) = Integer 1b 
Integer 2a - (equation) = Integer 2b
```

Neither integer 1a/1b will be 0 but I want to repeat this process until one of the integers reaches 0 or becomes a negative number and then print the final value of whichever integer didn't reach 0 and which integer reached 0.

Ideally, the end result would be something like:

```
 Integer 1 = 203 
 Integer 2 = 0
```

Comment: I can't make sense of what you are asking... what is (equation)? why would why would any of those values continue to reduce after the first evaluation when each is its own variable

Comment: Please post **what you've tried so far, and where did you encounter problems**. 
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Will this be the solution:

```
def f(i1,i2,eq):
    i1=i1-eq
    i2=i2-eq
    while i1>0 and i2>0:
        return f(i1,i2,eq)
    return {'i1':i1,'i2':i2}
```

However, after I received the comments on my answer, I felt compelled to rewrite the code:

```
def f(i1,i2,eq):
    while i1>0 and i2>0:
        i1=i1-eq
        i2=i2-eq
    return {'i1':i1,'i2':i2}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of a loop that will always run once?

Comment: Besides, what's the purpose of blowing the recursion limit for something that could be done in a loop?